# Excel formula to convert boolean values into {0, 1}

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

What is the Excel formula to convert boolean values `{FALSE, TRUE}` into `{0, 1}`?

Supposing there is one shorter than `=IF(cond,1,0)`.

Comment: Interestingly,  `=a1+a2` will return the numeric sum of logicals, but `=sum(a1:a2)` will not.  Excel 2013.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You could do it by casting.  The "int" function rounds to the nearest integer.  If the boolean value is in A1, the formula would be:

```
=INT(A1)
```

Comment: Similar to this, `=ROUND(A1,0)` does the same thing in this context.

Comment: Or `=CEILING(A1,1)`

Comment: Thanks, the cast was the "standard" way I was looking for. It didn't occur me to try that, I was actually expecting it to be "harder"...

Answer (score 15):

`--` is the most common way to convert boolean into int - that's why you see functions that have the `--` in them for this very reason. it will turn an array of {TRUE,FALSE,FALSE} into {1,0,0} which can them be used to multiply other arrays

Example:

returning the total sales from region that is 9 or lower:

```
Team    Sales
1       $20
2       $30
11      $90
```

formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A4<=9),B2:B4)
```

Calculation

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(True,True,False),($20,$30,$90))
=SUMPRODUCT((1,1,0),($20,$30,$90))
=1 * $20 + 1 * $30 + 0 * $90
=$20 + $30 + $0
=$50
```

Comment: @fixer1234, Does that edit help?

Comment: I had seen on the web the `--` method, but I must admit that using the formula `INT` is far more clear and elegant. :)

Comment: It is strange that double negation became the excel standard for numification.  Looks like decrement when taken out of context.

Answer (score 9):

Multiply it by '1'. ex. True * 1 = 1 and False * 1 = 0.

For example, if cell A1 contains the boolean value, in a neighbouring cell, enter the formula:

```
=A1*1
```

**Note:** --True, True+0 and True/1 have the same effect.

Comment: This isn't necessarily more readable, but it is "shorter" than the formula in the question.

Comment: That's nice. But does that mean there's no built-in formula for the conversion? Something like "BOOLVAL" or "BOOLINT"?

Comment: That's quite useful, but I was looking for a more "proper" solution such as @dangowans's, so I'll accept his solution. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Both answers work on the same principle --applying a numerical operation to a Boolean value will return a numerical answer.

Comment: This is `numification` of a sort.  In Perl, `+0` is the standard numification operator, but I like the use of `*1` for making bools into bits.

Answer (score 1):

Since Excel 2007, there is the [N() function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/n-function-a624cad1-3635-4208-b54a-29733d1278c9) that converts anything that's not a number or date into 0 or 1.

`=N(TRUE)` returns `1`

`=N(FALSE)` returns `0`

`=N("Text")` returns `0`

`=N("30")` returns `0`

`=N(30)` returns `30`

---

There's one for text as well, which returns an empty string if parameter is not a text.

`=T("Text")` returns `"Text"`

`=T(3104)` returns `""`